# Participles to modify the subject of the main clause

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, participles

> "***Essos*** is an ***immense landmass*** located to the east of Westeros,
>   ***extending*** into the far east of the known world." (Here, "extending"
>   describes the ***Essos*** or does it describes the ***landmass***? )

Having seen this sentence above, I question came to my mind.

Can I use participles to modify the subject of the main clause when there is no connection between main clause and participle clause. For example:

> 1- "He is a bookworm, ***living*** in Canada. (He is a bookworm + He lives in
>   Canada, there is no connection between being bookworm and living in
>   Canada)
>
> 2- He, ***living*** in Canada, is a book worm. (I suppose, this placement would be more correct)

Answer (score 1):

As easy technique for checking this:
Take the original sentence: "Essos is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros, ***extending*** into the far east of the known world."

**And make the ing into a subject and verb phrase:**

"Essos is an immense landmass located to the east of Westeros and ***it extends*** into the far east of the known world."

It describes both, basically, since Essos is a landmass. Technically, it describes landmass.

Check this out:

"Essos, located to the East of Westeros,  is an immense landmass extending [or it extends] into the far east of the known world." There it is most easily observed. You can see that it comes right after the antecedent.

These clauses using ing verb forms are a style device used to cut down on the use of another verb, which would make the sentence a compound sentence.

Likewise, with: *He is a bookworm, **living** in Canada.*

can be rewritten as: *He is a bookworm **and he lives** in Canada*.

But: He, living in Canada, is a bookworm. is not very grammatical.

You could, if you wanted to write something like this:

Living in Canada [as he does], he does not like snow too much.

Comment: Real thanks. So a participle clause can be used to modify the subject of the main clause as in my example "He is a bookworm, living in Canada". Can we say that this usage is correct only when "two facts" are happening at the same time? (He is a bookworm at present time and he lives in Canada at present time). I am also wondering about why the grammar books or websites don't explain this usage of participle clauses. They always say something like this: Participle clauses give information about ***condition*** (with a similar meaning to an if-condition) , ***result***, ***reason*** or ***time***

Comment: And have one more sentence "It is about saving lives, ***starting*** with mine." (A line from a tv series) (Context: He talks about time travel to save lives including his life.) Can we say this participle is used to modify the subject "it" as in my example above? "It is about saving lives and ıt starts with mine."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Yes, you got it with the "starting" example! :) What I say and what they said are different parts of the same thing. I am showing the transformation to see what it refers to or modifies. They are referring to overall meaning or purpose of using it. :)

Comment: Thank you again . :) The thing gnawing my mind right now is that question : Can we say that this usage is correct only when "two facts" are happening at the same time? (He is a bookworm at present time and he lives in Canada at present time) I mean does the tense of participle clause depend on the tense of the main clause? If the main clause's tense is present tense then does the tense of the participle clause(when we rewrite the sentence as you did in your post) have to be present tense too?

Comment: I mean ıs there a chance to rewrite the sentence like this without extra context: "He is a bookworm and he lived in Canada."

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Yes, the clauses would have to cohere. I don't think the second clause can be in the past tense. It has to follow the tense. **They lived off the land, tilling the soil for 50 years**. = lived and tilled....see? But there may be some exception I can't think of right now.

Comment: So when participle claused is used to modify the subject of the main clause it basically omits the conjuction(and) + the subject(he) and turns the verb(live to living) into the participle form? "Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house, ***agreeing*** to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting". (Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house, and Cooper agreed to a large slice of cherry pie...,) In this usage of participle, does the conjuction of rewritten sentence have to be "and" ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden The conjunction does have to be and for purposes of illustrating the structure. the agreeing to a large slice of cherry pie **can be understood** as a result: since he agreed to a large slice of cherry pie. It is **how you can see he enjoyed it**. It could be viewed as adverbial.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions. I just want to get it. Can I use this structure when the actions in the clauses (main and participle) happen at different points in time? For example : "He played on the school team at primary school, ***playing*** the bass guitar in a band at highschool." to mean "He played football on the school team at primary school and he played the bass guitar in a band at highschool." (Both actions happens in the past but in different parts of the past and there is no cause result relation between them. "Playing football" happens some time before the "playing bass guitar"

Comment: @Talha Ozden I answered that already: the verbs have to be in the same TENSE. You are asking the **same** question again. :)

Comment: So this question is perfectly grammatically and understandable then? It seem kind of awkward to me "He played on the school team at primary school, playing the bass guitar in a band at highschool"

Comment: @TalhaÖzden IN primary school, IN high school

Comment: Hi @Lambie. Again me :) . Could you explain the use of comma in my examples? Is using comma in my examples wrong ? "He is a bookworm living in Canada" ""It is about saving lives starting with mine"

Comment: @TalhaÖzden If the comma had been wrong, I would have removed it. Please stop now, do you mind? I feel you are beginning to misuse my help.

Comment: Sorry :( You are right.