# Is the second part of these sentences a participial phrase, a relative clause, or a participle clause?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is the second part of these sentences a participial phrase, a relative clause, or a participle clause?

> Scientists and volunteers race against the clock every day, **working to save wildlife before time runs out.**

> People have drained many wetlands, **turning them into farm fields or sites for industries**.

Comment: I suggest you go and look up "relative clause" as  first step. Then, participial phrase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Participles to modify the subject of the main clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214734/participles-to-modify-the-subject-of-the-main-clause)